# Iphone voice to text & back to voice API

Tags: iphone, text-to-speech, voice-recognition

I want in my iphone app , Voice to Text and then back to Voice.

I tried searching on forum and Google and found some APIs like  OpenEars, Vocal Kit and tts , but these are all for English Languages and not for other languages like German , French and Spanish, Chinese, etc.

Is there any Free API for this and I am missing it on Google or there isn't any API for this? Please Help

The existing apps in App Store like Jibbigo and MLD are using such functionality , so what are they using??

**ANSWER by Paul Dixon**

The Nuance API is free for development but asks to purchase before going live in the APP Store, so it should be accepted that there is no free API ,,, please help guys

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I conclude that there is no free and open project till now for my case

Answer (score 4):

Nuance offers a speech recognition and TTS API for mobile devices.

http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/

According to this [post](http://blog.dragonmobileapps.com/2011/01/mobile-app-developer-dragon-mobile-sdk.html) speech recognition is available in eight languages and TTS in 35 languages.

Comment: great, +1 for u,  but not a free api, it asks for purchasing before app going to the market , is there any free API available....

Answer (score 1):

[OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears/configuring/) is free and they have some good support. As you've noted, it doesn't do multilingual.

A commercial tts product that does multilingual, since you'll probably never find a free open product with multilingual support, is [Acapela](http://www.acapela-for-iphone.com/).

Comment: but as I said I want multilingual and they only support Engish

Comment: I suspect you won't be getting multilingual, open and free, unless Google or Apple or some other giant with the chops makes one. At present, I don't think one exists for free.

Comment: OpenEars developer here -- just wanted to mention that OpenEars now supports Spanish as well as English.

Answer (score 1):

I think **iSpeech** meets your requirement correctly.

It's a paid API but you will be provided with good support.

check the price list here  : **https://www.ispeech.org/developer/purchase/plans**

Also try **"AT&T Speech API SDK for iOS"** -  https://code-api-att.com/NativeSDK/PROD/docs/...

Answer (score 0):

what about [OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears/)?

Free and allows commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [VocalKit](https://github.com/KingOfBrian/VocalKit). Based of CMU Pocketsphinx and for the iPhone.

Comment: but as I said I want multilingual and they only support Engish

Comment: AFAIK you can create a language model and train it for new languages?

Answer (score 0):

[www.ispeech.org](http://www.ispeech.org) ...
It works against a server ( I think ) but depends on what you want to do it may be usefull to you!.